# How to set MBR to Linux Partition instead of GRUB

Tags: linux-mint, partition, grub2, grub, mbr

I have a Linux Mint 17.1 Partition at */dev/sda1* and another Mint 17.1 Partition at */dev/sda5*. How do I set the MBR to boot into */dev/sda1* instead of the GRUB menu? I know how to use GParted to delete the */dev/sda5* partition but not how to set the MBR.

Comment: the MBR cannot boot into sda5 as it does not know about extended partitions. You need grub or another boot loader for that. Just make sure /dev/sda1 has the boot flag and sda1 should boot

Comment: I have /dev/sda1 with a boot flag, it still boots into GRUB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grub is a piece of software that is installed in the MBR.

Delete sda5 and run grub-update or change grub config manually to boot from sda1, Maybe this howto can help you.

http://www.techsupportforum.com/357-how-to-configure-grub-bootloader-in-mint-linuxubuntu/

If grub is installed on sda u can change the grub config to boot from sda1.
If not try to install grub on sda.

```
$sudo grub-install /dev/sda
$sudo update-grub
```

If grub-install gives problems, you can install manually from the Grub shell with:

1. grub
2. root (hd0,0)
3. setup (hd0)
4. quit